# What is this kalanchoe-like plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents

My grandmother has this plant on her sunny windowsill. She barely waters it. It's grown quite leggy as the winters here (in Ireland) are quite dark, but overall it's gotten much bigger during its time at her house (according to Granny).

Leaves are kalancho-ic (rubbery feel, jagged edge) but I've personally never seen anything like it. Anyone any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an ordinary *Kalanchoe blossfeldiana*  - it needs a bigger, proper pot with drainage holes, and cutting  back to about 1-2 inches all over. Your grandmother might remember it as a small plant bought in flower originally, perhaps. It's grown like this because it does not have enough root room and is unable to put out new stems and be the bushy plant it's meant to be. After cutting back and repotting, find a sunny spot for it if  possible, although mine flowered again left standing on a windowsill in bright daylight with very little sun indoors. 
'

This link https://www.plantsrescue.com/kalanchoe-blossfeldiana/ suggests cutting back and moving outdoors during the warm months of summer, but as I say, mine  flowered again with just keeping it indoors. My own plant has become rather leggy (probably needs more sun) and now its finished flowering, I am about to cut it back hard to encourage more bushiness.

Comment: If you cut it back, use the pieces as cuttings. Then you will have 4 or 5 plants, not one!